# Striping a directory in lustre

Tags: filesystems, lustre

What exactly happens when a directory has a default layout in lustre?

As far as I know, if a directory has a default layout then whatever striping parameters are set for the directory are applied to the files created in that directory (unless mentioned explicitly). However, I tried for it but could not see that.

I mentioned the stripe count for directory=2 (`lfs setstripe -c 2 /mnt/lustre/directory`), and created the file inside it using `lfs setstripe /mnt/lustre/directory/file1` but when I do `lfs getstripe /mnt/lustre/directory/file1` I could see stripe count=1.

Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try creating a file without using `lfs setstripe` (e.g. `touch /mnt/lustre/directory/file1`)? When I tried creating a file inside striped directory using touch command it worked as expected (`getstripe` command returned `lmm_stripe_count:   2` value).